# How to show bar values with g.raphael?

Tags: javascript, graph, raphael

I can't seem to figure out how to add values ontop of the bars with g.raphael.

In one the examples I found:

https://github.com/kennyshen/g.raphael/blob/master/examples/barchart/barchart_hoverCol.html

its possible to show the value when the mouse hovers the bar. But I need to figure out how to always show the values ontop of the bars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to look at `chart.bars`? This is more or less how I did it:

```
for (var i=0, l=chart.bars.length; i<l; i++) {
  var bar=chart.bars[i];
  //raphael points at an instance of g.raphael
  bar.count_label = raphael
    .text( bar.x - bar.w + (2*dO.padding), bar.y, bar.value || "0")
    .attr( 'text-anchor', 'start' )
    .insertAfter( bar );
}
```